# Java Spring: Make POST Request with Multiple parameters

Tags: java, spring, rest, http, spring-boot

I am trying to model a REST call as such in Spring:
`guess {game: 'cdaeaa', guess: 'e' }`
that outputs the following:
`{gameId: 'cdaeaa', word: '____', incorrect: 1, status: 'ACTIVE'}`

I essentially need to make a function which takes two paramaters. It should return the game data. The game class is the following:

```
public class Game {

private final String gameId;
private final String word;
private String guessedWord;
private Set<Character> guessedChars;
private GameStatus status;
private int incorrectGuesses;
private static final int MAX_TRIES = 7;}
```

However, when I make a call as such:
`http://localhost:8080/guess/{asewqd}/{c}`
(It doesn't matter whether I put the stuff in braces in quotes or not.)
I get the following error: [image]

```
//POST
//make guess
@RequestMapping(value = "/guess/{game}/{guess}", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Game makeGuess(@PathVariable String game, @PathVariable String guess, HttpSession session) throws GameDoesNotExistException, InvalidCharacterException{
    Game g = getGame(game,session);

    String gameId = g.getId();
    if(gameId.equals(game) && guess.length() > 0) {
        boolean correct = compareWords(guess, g);
        if(!correct){
            g.incIncorrect_guesses();
        }
        g.setStatus();
    }
    else{
        if(!gameId.equals(game)) {
            throw new GameDoesNotExistException(game);
        }
        else{
            throw new InvalidCharacterException(guess);
        }
    }
    g = getGame(game,session);

    return g;
}
```

Comment: You need to call to `http://localhost:8080/%project-name%/guess/{asewqd}/{c}` instead of `http://localhost:8080/guess/{asewqd}/{c}`, replacing %project-name% with your project's name.

Comment: What do u mean by project name?

Comment: The deployed application name so for instance if your project is called game the url would be http://localhost:8080/game/guess/{asewqd}/{c}

Comment: The artifactId in pom.xml.

Comment: That doesn't work. I get a 404 error.

Comment: Since i do not think, that you want to know how to POST with multiple parameters but you want to know WHEN to use POST and WHEN to use GET you should read up that one (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp) and use a GET with multiple path variables.

Answer (score 2):

HTTP 405 means that you try to use HTTP GET instead of HTTP POST.

Comment: But I have method = RequestMethod.POST

Comment: Yes, your Method ACCEPTS only POST. But as you can read the last line in your error message, you're requesting a get. To test a POST request you should use Postman (https://www.getpostman.com/)

Comment: @jdickel This is what happens with curl. curl "http://localhost:8080/guess/{vcdvnt}/{b}"
{"timestamp":"2018-04-27T12:16:49.125+0000","status":405,"error":"Method Not Allowed","message":"Request method 'GET' not supported","path":"/guess/vcdvnt/b"}

Answer (score 0):

You use your browser to make the request. Browser use GET method by default.

Use an adapted tool, like curl or postman to make your POST requests.